# Apache Cordova installation ERROR

Tags: node.js, cordova, cmd, npm, installation

I tried to install Apache Cordova like they do it in the "get started" section of their website. First I install Node.js and npm, but as I tried to install the Cordova npm package I get the following error.

[image]

Here is the npm-debug.log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'appcelerator',
1 verbose cli   '--color',
1 verbose cli   'false' ]
2 info using npm@2.11.3
3 info using node@v0.12.7
4 verbose install initial load of C:\Users\hoerdtf\AppData\Roaming\npm\package.json
5 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from C:\Users\hoerdtf\AppData\Roaming\npm\package.json
6 silly cache add args [ 'appcelerator', null ]
7 verbose cache add spec appcelerator
8 silly cache add parsed spec { raw: 'appcelerator',
8 silly cache add   scope: null,
8 silly cache add   name: 'appcelerator',
8 silly cache add   rawSpec: '',
8 silly cache add   spec: '*',
8 silly cache add   type: 'range' }
9 silly addNamed appcelerator@*
10 verbose addNamed "*" is a valid semver range for appcelerator
11 silly addNameRange { name: 'appcelerator', range: '*', hasData: false }
12 silly mapToRegistry name appcelerator
13 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
14 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
15 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/appcelerator
16 verbose addNameRange registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/appcelerator not in flight; fetching
17 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/appcelerator
18 verbose request no auth needed
19 info attempt registry request try #1 at 09:26:46
20 verbose request id c48a8e708e170ca1
21 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/appcelerator
22 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
23 info attempt registry request try #2 at 09:26:56
24 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/appcelerator
25 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
26 info attempt registry request try #3 at 09:27:56
27 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/appcelerator
28 verbose stack Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
28 verbose stack     at Error (native)
28 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:929:36)
28 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:104:17)
28 verbose stack     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:460:8)
29 verbose cwd D:\
30 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
31 error argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "-g" "install" "appcelerator" "--color" "false"
32 error node v0.12.7
33 error npm  v2.11.3
34 error code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
35 error self signed certificate in certificate chain
36 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
36 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
37 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Maybe anyone could help me?

Thank you!

Comment: do you have install java?

Comment: Yes Java is istalled! Java 7 and 8.

Comment: please install java 8 only and set envoironment path about java 8 and check java version with **java --version** in cmd then try again

Comment: Poorly it still not work. I always get the same error.

Comment: some how it's npm bug please upgrade your npm with **npm -g install npm** then try again

Comment: I get the same error message if I try to install npm. :(

Comment: ok remove node.js from control paanel and try to download new latest one from https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: I installed it 2 hours ago, I guess it will be the latest version of node.js and npm.

Comment: fire this **npm set strict-ssl false** and try again

Comment: or try this http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78085451721/npms-self-signed-certificate-is-no-more

Comment: Windows:


SET npm_config_strict-ssl=false
npm install npm -g --ca=null
npm --version

Comment: Thank so much! It works now after I set of strict-ssl. Yesterday I had the same problem with the Atom package manager.

Comment: glad to help you... :) Happy coding...

Comment: should i put answer of it? and you will gone approve as answer?

Comment: **Of course!** ;) Otherwise I would add it under the Question.

Comment: ok adding answer with some links from where i found solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to follwoing **npm’s Self-Signed Certificate is No More**

You can disable certificate with following command: **npm set strict-ssl false**

1. https://coderwall.com/p/c2njkg/fix-npm-self_signed_cert_in_chain-or-cert_untrusted-errors
2. http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78085451721/npms-self-signed-certificate-is-no-more

It's already helped you i added answer so some one else facing issue can also resolve it.

Thank you.